# Simulation of data using r in long format

Tags: r

I want some assistance in certain simulation and I want to repeat the 10 year data (1953-1963) 20 times and get the data in the long format as follows:

```
nyears     Value
    1953       12.0
    1954       250.0
    1955       23.55
    ................
    1963       0.25
    1953       7.0
    1954       5.6
    1955       6.5
    .............
    1963      7.3
```

My code:

```
sims <- 10
nyears <- 1953:1963
Pop_Growth <- sapply(1:sims, function(x) {
  ntimes = 20
  N0 = 60
  N = vector(length = ntimes)
  N[1] = N0
  
  for (t in 2:ntimes) {
    N[t] = N[t - 1] + rnorm(ntimes, mean= 0, sd=1)
  }
  N
})
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you elaborate further as to how you want the data tp be generated?

Comment: Your current code generates a matrix with 10 columns and 20 observations.
Do you want to keep those columns in the tidy/long version? In other words, is each line in your matrix one observation with 10 different variables (i.e. each column represents a town or region)?

Comment: @Nicholas,  I want 200 observatiions i.e (10 years and each 10 years as one time series should be multiplied or generated 20 times, i.t 10*20 = 200 observation and I want those data to be arranged in long format with column nyears or year and the generated value, remember the years from 1953-1963 should be repeated 20 times accordingly.

Comment: @ Onyambu, the data is generated as random walk as I showed within the function and random noise, i.e N[t] = N[t - 1] + rnorm ntimes, mean= 0, sd=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be simplified greatly.

```r
### ans1
years <- 1953:1963
ntimes <- 20
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(
  Year = rep(years, each = ntimes),
  Value = rnorm(length(years) * ntimes, mean = 0, sd = 1)
)
dat$Value <- 60 + ave(dat$Value, dat$Year, FUN = cumsum)
head(dat)
#   Year    Value
# 1 1953 61.37096
# 2 1953 60.80626
# 3 1953 61.16939
# 4 1953 61.80225
# 5 1953 62.20652
# 6 1953 62.10040
```

The `ave` step is to ensure we do the cumulative-sum by `Year`. This can be done inside `sapply` if you really prefer, though it adds little except computation time (it will be slightly slower).

```r
### ans2
set.seed(42)
dat2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(years, function(yr) {
  data.frame(Year = yr, Value = 60 + cumsum(rnorm(ntimes, mean = 0, sd = 1)))
}))
#   Year    Value
# 1 1953 61.37096
# 2 1953 60.80626
# 3 1953 61.16939
# 4 1953 61.80225
# 5 1953 62.20652
# 6 1953 62.10040
```

The first execution time (for this small problem) is 1/6th of the second with identical results.

```
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result             memory                  time             gc                  
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>             <list>                  <list>           <list>              
1 ans1          262us  297.3us     2714.    24.1KB     4.21  1290     2      475ms <df[,2] [220 x 2]> <Rprofmem[,3] [37 x 3]> <bch:tm [1,292]> <tibble [1,292 x 3]>
2 ans2         1.79ms   2.15ms      429.    51.5KB     4.22   203     2      473ms <df[,2] [220 x 2]> <Rprofmem[,3] [55 x 3]> <bch:tm [205]>   <tibble [205 x 3]>
```

Comment: that is really great, but I want each year to come in alternative way, I think, Year = rep(years, each = ntimes) should be Year = rep(years, times = ntimes).

Comment: can you hint me how can I do the same problem using another equation like N[t]<-exp(Y)*N[t-1]+rnorm(length(years) * ntimes,0,1) rather than random walk?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think you're going to have to explain things better than throwing out the formula. What are `t` and `Y`, if you're using `years` for something else? Is `t` each year (and `years` lists all of them)?

Comment: y can be generated from normal distribution (as an exponent) and t for each year!

Comment: If I'm interpreting that correct, then it appears you are mixing mathematical notation with R syntax. That is, if `Y ~ Norm(0,1)` then we could infer that a new variable `Z ~ Norm(0,1)` and therefore `N[t] = exp(Y)*N[t-1] + Z`, meaning your expression has two random variables. If that's not the case, then please explain why you mean by saying *"Y can be generated from normal distribution"* as well as adding another random variable.

Comment: you are quite right! Thanks for your understanding! Rather than adding another variable, Y can be in such a form: Y~ intercept + slope * N[t-1] and the intercept and slope values can be randomly assigned but you have nailed my idea  in your comment.

Comment: Two ways to do it: (1) `zoo::rollapply` where each iteration pulls its own random numbers, but its performance will be slower (if you have lots of data), since 1-by-1 random is much slower than all-at-once random; or (2) `Reduce(.., accumulate=TRUE)` using logic from https://stackoverflow.com/a/68834888/3358272, where we iterate over the indices of the values and not the values themselves.