# R pass function to accumulate

Tags: r, purrr, accumulate

I want to use this accumulate example changing the fixed "growth" for a variable in the data farme. Original example: https://community.rstudio.com/t/row-wise-iteration-in-a-dataframe-where-each-row-depends-on-previous-values/38725/2

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

x <- tibble(a = c(1:10),
            b = c(seq(100, 140, 10), rep(NA_real_, 5)) )

x$growth = runif(10, 0.001, 0.09)

fill_in <- function(prev, new, growth = 0.03) {
  if_else(!is.na(new), new, prev * (1 + growth))
}

x <- x %>%
  mutate(b = accumulate(b, fill_in))
```

This works, but I can´t replace 0.03 with x$growth. Any Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of how `accumulate` (and `accumulate2`) is structured, we cannot iterate over just `b`, we need to include something like `c(b, growth)` for each point. For this, instead of passing `b`, we'll pass a `list` of vectors, which can be produced with:

```r
with(x, pmap(list(b, growth), c))
# [[1]]
# [1] 100.0000000   0.0265944
# [[2]]
# [1] 110.00000000   0.07115916
# [[3]]
# [1] 120.00000000   0.03739895
# [[4]]
# [1] 130.00000000   0.07958855
# [[5]]
# [1] 140.00000000   0.08470159
# [[6]]
# [1]          NA 0.005054528
# [[7]]
# [1]         NA 0.04800139
# [[8]]
# [1]         NA 0.08042529
# [[9]]
# [1]         NA 0.05007772
# [[10]]
# [1]         NA 0.04163871
```

With this, we can now accumulate:

```r
fill_in2 <- function(prev, new) if (is.na(new[1])) prev[1]*(1+new[2]) else new[1]
options(pillar.sigfig = 5)
x %>%
  mutate(b = accumulate(pmap(list(b, growth), c)[-1], .init = b[1], fill_in2))
# # A tibble: 10 x 3
#        a      b    growth
#    <int>  <dbl>     <dbl>
#  1     1 100    0.026594 
#  2     2 110    0.071159 
#  3     3 120    0.037399 
#  4     4 130    0.079589 
#  5     5 140    0.084702 
#  6     6 140.71 0.0050545
#  7     7 147.46 0.048001 
#  8     8 159.32 0.080425 
#  9     9 167.30 0.050078 
# 10    10 174.27 0.041639
```

The reason I do both `pmap(..)[-1]` and `.init=b[1]` is because with the default behavior of `accumulate`, the first element of `.x` is passed-through as-is; in this case, that would pass `c(100, 0.0266)` as the first return value, which is not what we want. To fix that, we remove that from the `pmap`'d list and add `b[1]` as the initialization value (`.init=`) of `accumulate`.

BTW: this is using the *current* value of `growth` applied to the *previous* value of `b`.

Another BTW: your use of `fill_in` used `if_else`. While it works, it is unnecessary and inappropriate. If one is looking to `if` an object that will always be length 1, then use `if` (and optionally `else`); if one is looking to condition on a *vector* of logicals, then use `ifelse`/`if_else`. While one can use `if_else` when you know that it will always always always be length 1, there is overhead and likely other things going on that are completely unnecessary (and in base R, `ifelse` has consequences and side-effects with non-trivial class data, so its use should be managed).

Since `accumulate` calls your function with exactly one row's worth of data at a time, the use of `if` is more appropriate.

---

Data

```r
set.seed(123)
x <- tibble(a = c(1:10),
            b = c(seq(100, 140, 10), rep(NA_real_, 5)),
            growth = runif(10, 0.001, 0.09))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! that is what I am looking for. One more question, how do yo define fill_in2?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I added it in (plus a few notes). See my edit.